# using react native flexbox to properly display button on top left hand side

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am following this tutorial online: https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e

I want to take his example and have a cancel button int he top left-hand corner while the title is still properly displayed at the top center just like in his example. However, When I add the cancel button, the title always appears right next to it on the left hand side. what am I doing wrong with my flexbox styling?

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import images from '../../config/images';


const HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
const HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 60 : 73;
const HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE = HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT - HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
    };
  }

  _renderScrollViewContent() {
    const data = Array.from({ length: 30 });
    return (
      <View style={styles.scrollViewContent}>
        {data.map((_, i) => (
          <View key={i} style={styles.row}>
            <Text>{i}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const headerTranslate = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [0, -HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const imageOpacity = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 2, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [1, 1, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
    const imageTranslate = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [0, 100],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const titleScale = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 2, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [1, 1, 0.8],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
    const titleTranslate = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 2, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [0, 0, -8],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.fill}>
        <StatusBar
          translucent
          barStyle="light-content"
          backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.251)"
        />
        <Animated.ScrollView
          style={styles.fill}
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          onScroll={Animated.event(
            [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
            { useNativeDriver: true },
          )}
        >
          {this._renderScrollViewContent()}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.header,
            { transform: [{ translateY: headerTranslate }] },
          ]}
        >

        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.bar,
            {
              transform: [
                { scale: titleScale },
                { translateY: titleTranslate },
              ],
            },
          ]}
        >
         <Image
        //style={styles.icon}
        source={images.icons.cancel}/> // cancel button/icon I want to add

        <Text style={styles.title}>Title</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#2c6da4',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    width: null,
    height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  bar: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 28 : 38,
    height: 32,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    flex: 1 // added this but does not display in the center.

  },
  scrollViewContent: {
    marginTop: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
  },
  row: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
   //alignItems: 'flex-start',
   //flex: 1,
  //justifyContent: 'flex-start'

  },
});
```

This is what I am currently getting:
[image]

```
/config/images.js:
const images = {
    icons: {
        cancel: require('../images/cancel.png')

    }
};

export default images;
```

Comment: `import images from '../../config/images';` - can you past the contents of that file?

Comment: I add the contents of the file you requested

Comment: is this still actual? could you provide image as how it should be